# ROS beginner_tutorials (17th tutorial) Error

Tags: ros, c++, beginner-tutorials, cmake, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to learn ROS. So far I had many errors. Thanks to ROS Answers, I found solutions to them so far.

I could not solve this one, so here is my question.

I get this error when I am trying the 17th tutorial - Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)-

```
irem@willis:~$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials
irem@willis:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials$ make
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package beginner_tutorials
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: package/stack beginner_tutorials depends on non-existent package std_msgs


CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  

  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
  'beginner_tutorials'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70687/ros-beginner_tutorials-(17th-tutorial)-error/) by [mary](https://answers.ros.org/users/5710/mary/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was.In the end I had to reinstall everything. It still did not work. I reinstalled ubuntu and ros again xD Still thanks for your response :)

---

Originally posted by [mary](https://answers.ros.org/users/5710/mary/) with karma: 43 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is rospack package installed ? (check it out doing `roscd rospack`, if you have an error message, it is not installed)

If it isn't installed try to do 'sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rospack' to install it.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1